# How to modify existing podcast information?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I'm a podcaster and I already submitted a podcast. However, I want to change the "Podcast Website" link under the Links section.

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/podcast/insight-for-living-canada/id407284701

How do I do that? Do I login somewhere where I can manage all the podcasts I submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You do this by changing the `<link>` tag in your podcast's RSS feed. iTunes will automatically pick up the change the next time it scans your feed.

The specifics of how to do this change depending on your podcast host, so if you need help your best bet is to contact their support folks.